# Dynamic page not being created (again)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to figure out how to overload my Opponents page, such that if I call /Opponents with no arguments I get a summary page, but it I call it with an argument (/Opponents/Centerville) it renders the detail page.

This is similar to a question I asked yesterday, but I was using a separate OpponentsIndex page, to which I was redirecting the call to /Opponents. Now, instead of doing the redirect, I want it to display the summary page directly.

My code is working for the Centerville page, but I can't figure out how to get the Opponents summary to work. I'm getting a 404 Page Not Found error.

```
Opponents.cshtml.cs
using Alpha.Data;
using Alpha.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Alpha.Pages {
    public class OpponentsModel : PageModel {
        private AlphaContext context;

        public IEnumerable<GameSummary> GameSummaries { get; set; }
            =Enumerable.Empty<GameSummary>();

        public OpponentsModel(AlphaContext ctx) {
            context = ctx;
        }
 
        public IActionResult OnGet(string Opponent) {
            if (@Opponent is null)
                return new PageResult();
            else
                GameSummaries = context.GameSummaries.Where(s => s.Opponent == @Opponent);
                return new PageResult();
        }
    }
}

Opponents.cshtml
@page "{Opponent}"
@model Alpha.Pages.OpponentsModel

@{
    bool isError = false;
}

@try{
    ViewData["Title"] = @Model.GameSummaries.First().Opponent;
}

catch{
    isError = true;
}

@if (isError == true){
    <p>HTML goes here for the /Opponents page</p>
}
else{
    <p>HTML goes here for the /Opponents/@Model.GameSummaries.First().Opponent page</p>
}
```

Additional question: currently I'm using a try/catch to determine if the page was called with an argument or not. Is there a better way for me to do this?

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a `?` to your `@page` as described in @MikeBrind's [article](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/339/optional-parameters-in-razor-pages-routing). The updated directive is `@page "{Opponent?}"`

Comment: Thanks @DaveB, that fixed it. I appreciate the reference to the article. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.